# Как реализовать данную сущность моделей в Django?

Tags: python, django, django-model

имеется модель `Country`, например, с такими полями:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Также имеется модель `Continent`, у которой такие поля:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

И имеется третья модель, пусть будет `Location`. У нее есть поля `country` и `continent`, при чем в обоих этих полях можно вести только одно значение, то есть связь должна быть `ForeignKey`. И поле `country` должно зависеть от привязанных значений  к выбранному на текущий момент `continent`. То есть при выборе `country` там должны быть доступны только те страны, который были привязан к выбранному на данный момент `continent`. Как такое можно организовать и привязать к админке Django?

Comment: Возможно поможет limit_choices_to для ForeignKey

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать виджет `ModelChoiceField` для поля country в модели `Location`. В методе `__init__` формы для этого поля можно установить `queryset` на основе выбранного значения для поля `continent`.

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        continent = self.data.get('continent')
        if continent:
            continent = Continent.objects.get(pk=continent)
            self.fields['country'].queryset = continent.countries.all()
        else:
            self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.none()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['continent', 'country']
```

Чтобы это организовать и привязать к админке Django возьмите `LocationForm` в классе `ModelAdmin` для модели `Location`:

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LocationForm

admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

Это заставит Django использовать ваш форму в админке вместо стандартной. Когда пользователь выбирает значение для поля `continent`, `queryset` для поля `country` будет обновляться в соответствии с выбранным значением для `continent`.